# Android Studio res folder in external libraries disappeared

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I used to view resources of external libraries in the Project Panel of Android Studio. But somehow for one of my projects the res directory is not visible in Project Panel > External Libraries > lib name

Only AndroidManifest.xml shows in the panel, and it has weird icon. When I hover the icon with cursor a popup appears: "Excluded from compilation".

How it used to look (screenshot from another project):

[image: Fragment of project explorer with res folder in external library]

How it looks now:

[image: Fragment of project explorer without res folder in the same external library]

I followed the steps from "File > Repair IDE" but with no success. One part of it was "Invalidate caches and restart" and it wasn't solution for me.

It seems that I changed some setting, but I don't know which one has to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was ensuring that `.gradle` is NOT in the list of ignored folders.

The setting is located in `Preferences → Editor → File Types → Ignored Files and Folders`